# ArrayList через socket

Tags: c#, сокет

Уважаемые ХэшКодовцы, каким образом можно передать ArrayList через сокеты?

Comment: Зачем вам ArrayList? Это старый класс, который был нужен ровно до появления generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через сокеты Вы можете передать массив байт, не более, а далее то, во что Вы это положите, Ваше дело. Такое понятие как протокол знаете? Вот он как раз описывает то, что Вы отправляете и принимаете.

Comment: Ага. И к умному слову протокол можно добавить (хотя и не 100% обязательно) умное слово Serialization